# Zapier Facebook lead ads is not letting lead information through when zap is active

Tags: facebook, post, zapier

I'm trying to transfer new leads from facebook to our crm automatically.
While testing, everything seemed to be fine and everything worked flawlessly but once i activated the zap, trigger stopped letting data through. Instead of actual email in the data zapier shows 101262649__email string.

[Here is a picture of my task history.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQdgI.png)

Does anyone else have the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't, this is a good thing to get in touch with Zapier support about: https://zapier.com/contact

Comment: You have the wrong field mapping, correct field mapping with the latest test result from trigger.